# disabled same nth-child div on other container

Tags: jquery

Im working on a simple menu which add **active** class on div when clicked then remove **active** class on sibling element.

Currently, I have two menus, What I want is when I clicked on an element, the equal child position on the other container add a **disabled** class.

example: I clicked *#1* on left menu, on the right menu the *#1* becomes disabled.

Hope you understand me.

thanks.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/mKdPyP)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selection div').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.selection{
  display: inline-block;
}
.selection div{
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selection div.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
.selection div.disabled{
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="selection left">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="selection right">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disables the element at the same level on the other side when clicked and does nothing when a disabled element is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selection > div').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            var otherSide = $(this).parent().hasClass('left') ? '.right' : '.left';
            var otherElement = $(otherSide).children().removeClass('disabled').eq($(this).index());
            $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).hasClass('active') ? otherElement.addClass('disabled') : otherElement.removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.selection{
  display: inline-block;
}
.selection div{
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selection div.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
.selection div.disabled{
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="selection left">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="selection right">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything look good, but when one div has `disabled` class, it should remove both class too.

Comment: @Pedram Not sure which two classes you want removed but a div cannot be disabled and active at a time, already.

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful, but it works :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.selection div').click(function(){
var classs=$(this).attr("class");
$(this).removeClass();
$('.'+classs).css('background-color','white');
$('.'+classs).css('color','white'); 
$(this).css('display','visible');   
$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
$(this).css('display','visible');
});
});
```

```css
.selection{
  display: inline-block;
}
.selection div{
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selection div.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
.selection div.disabled{
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="selection left">
    <div class="button1">1</div>
    <div class="button2">2</div>
    <div class="button3">3</div>
    <div class="button4">4</div>
    <div class="button5">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="selection right">
    <div class="button1">1</div>
    <div class="button2">2</div>
    <div class="button3">3</div>
    <div class="button4">4</div>
    <div class="button5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you sir, but it didn't add disabled class on the opposite menu. also removing the active class wont affect the other container

Comment: so if u click one of the left item, all the right item disappear? or just the same item but in the right side?

Comment: only the siblings on that container sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `index` of the clicked item and then disable the item with the same index from the other list.

And for eg if you click on `1`, the other `1` will get disabled. When you click on `2` ( from the same list as the active `1` ) , the disabled `1` will get enabled. That's why you need the `otherDisabled` variable.

You can also add `pointer-events:none` to the `.disabled` class, so you can't `click` on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let item = $('.selection div')
  $(item).click(function() {
    let i = $(this).index(),
        disableMe = $(this).parents('.selection').siblings().find('div').eq(i),
        otherDisabled = disableMe.siblings()
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    disableMe.toggleClass('disabled')
    otherDisabled.removeClass('disabled')
    
  });
});
```

```css
.selection {
  display: inline-block;
}

.selection div {
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selection div.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}

.selection div.disabled {
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="selection left">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="selection right">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selection div').click(function(){
    var indexOfDiv = $(this).index();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.selection').siblings().find('div').eq(indexOfDiv).toggleClass('disabled');
  });
});
```